# Vanishing property of logarithmic derivative of zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I was trying to derive the explicit formula for the integrated Chebyshev $\psi$ function, $\psi_1$ defined as

\begin{equation}\psi_1(x)=\int_1^x\psi(y)dy\end{equation}

But I have stumbled upon one technicality, and that is showing that the quantity
\begin{equation}
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}
\end{equation}
vanishes as $|s|\to\infty$. I have a hunch that the logarithmic derivative of the zeta function vanishes as $|s|\to\infty$, but is it really true? If so, how?

Comment: For what values of $x$?

Comment: any fixed positive  value

Comment: Using the sum identity $\zeta(s) = \sum \frac{1}{n^s}$ valid for $\Re s>1$ we have $\zeta(s) \simeq 1 + \frac{1}{2^s}$ for large $s$ so $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}\simeq -\frac{\log(2)}{2^{s} + 1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\cdot\zeta'(n)=-\ln2.~$ The rest is trivial.